# Sass Mixin value is not getting passed on calling from @include

Tags: html, css, sass

I have couple of partials(say _one.scss and _two.scss) which am calling into a SASS. **_one.scss has following code**

```
@mixin wire($num) {
 .parts-field {
  height: 100%;
width: calc(100% * (1/$num) - 10px - 1px);
}
```

And in **_two.scss** has 
`.mytry {
  @include wire(3);
}`

**In my main.scss am doing the following**

```
@import "../../base/_one.scss"; 
@import "_two.scss";
```

When I check **main.css**, it shows the following:

```
.mytry .parts{
height: 100%;
width: calc(100% * (1/$num) - 10px - 1px);
}
```

Even though am saying `@include wire(3)`, I believe the 3 is not getting passed. Styles are not applying on the HTML either. Is there something fundamentally wrong am doing with param passing to mixins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use string interpolation, i.e. replace `$num` with `#{$num}`:

```
@mixin wire($num) {
  .parts-field {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% * (1/#{$num}) - 10px - 1px);
  }
}
```

The reason why this is needed because SASS will treat `(...)` as a calculation that has to be evaluated during compilation, and it does not know that `calc(...)`  should be interpreted as a string and not a mathematical expression.

Comment: Terri. I have gone through the 'http://sass-lang.com/guide' multiple times and is useful just to a limited part. Where can I do more reading to know the point you just mentioned? A good tutorial or better documentation?

Comment: There are a huge number of SASS tutorials on youtube to start with